# Align unnumbered chapters and reduce spacing in ToC (memoir)

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Consider this MWE.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\backmatter
\chapter{Index}
\end{document}
```

My book doesn't have sections, only chapters. I want to reduce the spacing between chapters in ToC and align the unnumbered chapter with the numbered one. How can I do this for `memoir` class? I have found several solution for KOMA-script, `report`, `article`, `book`, but none for `memoir`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memoir manual has a whole chapter on layout of the ToC (and otehr contents lists). In your case, changing the value of the length `\cftbeforechapterskip` can be used to set the vertical spacing. And playing with `\cftsetindents` and `\cftchapterpresnum` allows you to align the titles of numbered and unnumbered chapters. Complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% added to modify ToC layout
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt} %reduces spacing between titles
\cftsetindents{chapter}{1.em}{0em}     %indent titles 1em, allow 0em for numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\hspace{-1.em}}%so move the numbers to the left
% end addition

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}
\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\backmatter
\chapter{Index}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tip: use `-\cftchapterindent` in the `presnum` line, then you don't have to write the value twice